# Develop desktop apps using Xamarin for Windows and Mac OS?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio, xamarin.mac

I want to develop desktop application for Windows and Mac OS. Can I use Xamarin for this?

Comment: `Xamarin.Forms` has alpha support for building macOS GUI is you are looking a `Forms` approach, otherwise `Xamarin.Mac` can be used to create a "native" macOS UI and you can share the business logic of the app between platforms:  https://twitter.com/migueldeicaza/status/773234995473244160

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, but the support for Xamarin.Forms is not available right now for Xamarin.Mac. For Xamarin.UWP it is.

While using Xamarin.Mac, it is indeed using the Mono Framework, and you can develop on Xamarin Studio. The interfaces can be created either by code or with the Interface Builder on XCode. You can have more informations here : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/mac/getting_started/

Comment: Outside of Xamarin.Forms the general strategy with Xamarin is to provide a custom platform specific GUI while leveraging a common C# library of business specific logic. You could develop a majority of your application inside a shared library with a MVVM pattern (or similar) and have a mostly "thin" UI layer for Window / macOS.

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin.Forms has UWP and OSX (alpha) support. If you need WPF and/or GTK (to support also Linux), you can use something like [Xwt](https://github.com/mono/xwt) (used by MonoDevleop) or [Eto](https://github.com/picoe/Eto). Both allow you to choose which toolkit to use (i.e. Gtk backends can run on both Windows and Mac, or you use always the native backend, or Wpf on Windows and Gtk on Mac, etc.)

Comment: Sevo, do you have any links to back the OSX support bit ? Searched but can't find anything on it.

Comment: You can find the current dev code in https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/tree/macOS, but you'll need to build it manually, since its still WIP.

Answer (score 0):

With Xamarin/Mono you can use the GTK# wrapper that comes with it to build cross platform Windows/OSx/Nix applications.

Just be aware that the UI will look less native on Windows and OSx.